# Unexpected behavior of ML Logistic Regression?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence, logistic-regression

I am new to AI and ML so apologies if this is a stupid question.
I was reading about Logistic Regression, and found out it is a classification supervised ML model.

So I tried to code an example to give it a try. My idea was to see if the program was able to figure out the "rule" behind the label (Y) I established, which is "*Y = 1 if and only if X1 OR X2 is a multiple of 3 but not both, 0 otherwise*"

But as you can see the accuracy is very poor. Am I doing something wrong? Did I misunderstood the concept of Logistic Regression?

**DATASET**:

```
3,1,1
2,3,1
1,1,0
2,4,0
5,6,1
9,3,1
8,9,1
5,5,0
9,9,0
5,7,0
3,3,0
5,3,1
2,4,0
7,7,0
4,9,1
7,3,1
6,2,1
8,1,0
6,4,0
9,4,1
```

**CODE**:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import metrics
col_names = ['x1', 'x2', 'y']
multi3 = pd.read_csv("1.csv", header=None, names=col_names)
feature_cols = ['x1', 'x2']
X = multi3[feature_cols]
y = multi3.y
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=0)
logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = logreg.predict(X_test)
cnf_matrix = metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
print(cnf_matrix)
print("Accuracy:", metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
print("Precision:", metrics.precision_score(y_test, y_pred))
print("Recall:", metrics.recall_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[[1 2]
 [1 1]]
Accuracy: 0.4
Precision: 0.3333333333333333
Recall: 0.5
```

**EDIT**:

Source code of my comment below.

[image: WORKING EXAMPLE]

Comment: Funny thing when I changed the rule to "Y=1 if X1>5 OR X2>5, 0 otherwise" I got 92% accuracy (screenshot above)

Comment: You also changed a number of observations from 20 to 1000.

Answer (score 0):

You can visualize your data:

```
multi3.plot.scatter(x = "x1",y="x2", c = "y",cmap="viridis")
```

[image]

You can see there's no clear separation between your two different classes (0 or 1). So the accuracy you get, even though with a small test set, would be low, because x1 and x2 are not useful at all in discriminating the labels.

In the code you posted, you did it over a larger dataset and also simulated data, if we do something similar,

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,(60,2)),columns=['x1', 'x2'])
df['y'] = ((df['x1']>5) & (df['x2'] > 5)).astype(int)

logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(df[['x1','x2']], df['y'])
y_pred = logreg.predict(df[['x1','x2']])
cnf_matrix = metrics.confusion_matrix(df['y'], y_pred)
cnf_matrix

array([[49,  2],
       [ 2,  7]])
```

And of course, you can see that there is separation:

[image]

My guess is that the original dataset is wrong or has nothing to do with what you posted as an image.